# c - Are defined values slower than hard-coded numbers

Tags: c, performance, optimization, macros

this question might appear dumb to you but I couldn't find an answer to it and I want to be sure that it works as I think.

Recently I came across this code:

```
void RDP_G_SETBLENDCOLOR(void)
{
    Gfx.BlendColor.R = _SHIFTR(w1, 24, 8) * 0.0039215689f;
    Gfx.BlendColor.G = _SHIFTR(w1, 16, 8) * 0.0039215689f;
    Gfx.BlendColor.B = _SHIFTR(w1, 8, 8) * 0.0039215689f;
    Gfx.BlendColor.A = _SHIFTR(w1, 0, 8) * 0.0039215689f;

    if(OpenGL.Ext_FragmentProgram && (System.Options & BRDP_COMBINER)) {
        glProgramEnvParameter4fARB(GL_FRAGMENT_PROGRAM_ARB, 2, Gfx.BlendColor.R, Gfx.BlendColor.G, Gfx.BlendColor.B, Gfx.BlendColor.A);
    }
}
```

I understand that the 0.0039215689f (which refers to 1/255) is hard-coded for optimization reasons. 
Now imagine that I want to define it
for readability reasons (even if the name chosen here is not better, it's just for the example).

```
#define PIXEL_VALUE 0.0039215689f

void RDP_G_SETBLENDCOLOR(void)
{
    Gfx.BlendColor.R = _SHIFTR(w1, 24, 8) * PIXEL_VALUE;
    Gfx.BlendColor.G = _SHIFTR(w1, 16, 8) * PIXEL_VALUE;
    Gfx.BlendColor.B = _SHIFTR(w1, 8, 8) * PIXEL_VALUE;
    Gfx.BlendColor.A = _SHIFTR(w1, 0, 8) * PIXEL_VALUE;

    if(OpenGL.Ext_FragmentProgram && (System.Options & BRDP_COMBINER)) {
        glProgramEnvParameter4fARB(GL_FRAGMENT_PROGRAM_ARB, 2, Gfx.BlendColor.R, Gfx.BlendColor.G, Gfx.BlendColor.B, Gfx.BlendColor.A);
    }
}
```

Would this define make the code execution slower?

Comment: It is identical, macroses are expanded before a translation unit is compiled.

Comment: The compiler will take care of all this, its a one of translation, make things as readable and maintainable as possible and let the compiler worry about producing the assembler.

Comment: *I understand that the 0.0039215689f (which refers to 1/255) is hard-coded for optimization reasons.* A good compiler will automatically translate `1/255` to `0.0039215689f` on compile time by itself.

Comment: @tilz0R Or rather `1.0f/255.0f`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would this define make the code execution slower?

No, since these two code snippets are identical, because MACROS are expanded before a translation unit is compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Macros do text replacement. The code that gets compiled is exactly the same as if you copied and pasted the replacement text of the macro in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe they make no difference at all.

A macro is **a pattern of text replacement**. So it gets replaced **before** your code is compiled.

You can try preprocessing both files and see the difference in a terminal:

```
gcc -E 1.c -o 1.i
gcc -E 2.c -o 2.i
diff -u 1.i 2.i
```